# Unity 2D: Gravitational Pull

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

I'm working on a small game: I want all GameObjects to be pulled into the middle of the screen where they should collide with another GameObject.

I tried this attempt:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Planet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform bird;
    private float gravitationalForce = 5;
    private Vector3 directionOfBirdFromPlanet;
 
    void Start ()
    {
        directionOfGameObjectFromMiddle = Vector3.zero;
    }
 
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        directionOfGameObjectFromMiddle = (transform.position-bird.position).normalized;
        bird.rigidbody2D.AddForce (directionOfGameObjectFromMiddle * gravitationalForce);    
    }
}
```

sadly I can't get it to work. I've been told that I have to give the object that is **being** pulled another script but is it possible to do this just with one script that is used on the object **that pulls**?

Comment: `transform.position-gameobject.position` wouldn't even compile .... do you mean `bird.position`?

Comment: hey sorry, yes I meant that.

Comment: So you mean you have one planet and one bird ? or are there more objects?

Comment: also note that `bird.rigidbody2D` is deprecated .. you should be using `bird.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce` or even better directly make the field of type `public Rigidbody2D bird;` right away

Comment: actually I want there to be a lot of birds in the end. Like infinitely many. But I wanted to get it to work with just one bird first.

Comment: so what exactly is the issue currently? Do you have anything in your code controlling `velocity` of the bird directly? This would overrule your AddForce ... maybe the force is just to weak? Do you also set [`gravityScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html) to `0` ?

Comment: @derHugo I'm sorry Hugo but currently its very hard to follow because I just started of coding. I might be asking my question wrong. I will try again:

Comment: I want a bird that is somewhere on the screen to be pulled into the middle of the screen.

Comment: thank you for your patience and time by the way! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first you have a lot of typos / code that doesn't even compile.

You use e.g. once `directionOfBirdFromPlanet` but later call it `directionOfGameObjectFromMiddle` ;) Your `Start` is quite redundant.

As said `bird.rigidbody2D` is **deprecaded** and you should rather use `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` or even better directly make your field of type

```
public Rigidbody2D bird;
```

For having multiple objects you could simply assign them to a List and do

```
public class Planet : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Directly use the correct field type
    public List<Rigidbody2D> birds;

    // Make this field adjustable via the Inspector for fine tuning
    [SerializeField] private float gravitationalForce = 5;

    // Your start was redundant    

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // iterate through all birds
        foreach (var bird in birds)
        {
            // Since transform.position is a Vector3 but bird.position is a Vector2 you now have to cast
            var directionOfBirdFromPlanet = ((Vector2) transform.position - bird.position).normalized;

            // Adds the force towards the center
            bird.AddForce(directionOfBirdFromPlanet * gravitationalForce);
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the planet you reference all the `bird` objects

[image]

On the birds' `Rigidbody2D` component make sure to set

`Gravity Scale` -> `0`

you also can play with the `Linear Drag` so in simple words how much should the object slow down itself while moving

E.g. this is how it looks like with `Linear Drag = 0` so your objects will continue to move away from the center with the same "energy"

[image]

this is what happens with `Linear Drag = 0.3` so your objects lose "energy" over time

[image]